# Firebase Analytics Log Events is unable to show me the custom bundle value in the dashboard even a day

Tags: android, firebase, logging, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

This is how I am logging my custom bundle to the Firebase Analytics :

```
params.putString("event_name", event_name);
        params.putBoolean("env", BuildConfig.DEBUG_MODE);
        params.putString("user_id", user_id);
        params.putString("time_at", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        mFireBaseAnalytics.logEvent("SessionExp", params);
```

String "event_name" is visible but not the data.

The event has been called around 60 times but not showing a single param mentioned above.

[image: Please look at this, the LogEvent dashboard]

Comment: Have you tried to use debugview to see data in real time?

Comment: No. How does it affect the data on the dashboard? is there a chance that my data is not being logged to the FA?

Comment: Sometimes it just takes some time. This can is inconsistent, since it can take from 15 min to 24h (less frequent but it can happen).

Comment: Another thing I would like to point out is if your logs are showing that the events are being sent without any warning.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't tried the debugview to see the data. I am gonna try that and see if the data is being logged without any warning or not.